# Reading svg file through Java

Tags: java, svg

Can anyone provide me with an example program for reading an svg file.

Comment: Reading is just like any other file.  Perhaps you want to have it rendered into something?

Comment: i wrote a program and through that program im setting different kind of  images as my backgroung image.....bt when im doing with svg i cant display the image.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at the [Batik SVG Toolkit](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/):

> Batik is a Java-based toolkit for applications or applets that want to use images in the Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) format for various purposes, such as display, generation or manipulation.

Comment: thanq u  jon.........ya went through Batik Svg tool kit and i downloaded the tool kit and im new to java and i want a sample program for reading a svg file.......

Comment: @ashwanth: I suggest you look through all the documentation for Batik then. I'm sure there are plenty of examples there.