# reading svg file through java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading svg file through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067224/reading-svg-file-through-java)

i want a sample program for reading a svg file and displaying its content

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the batik project : [official website](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/)

They have a Swing component to display SVG graphics and you can also manipulate SVG files.

Comment: k tanqu.....can i get the exact link from which i can download the batik software exactly...

Comment: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/download.cgi Choose the version you need (probably JRE 1.4+)

Comment: No problem. You should accept one of the answers (all are the same) with the tick icon to say that you had an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) is a Java-based toolkit for applications or applets that want to use images in the Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) format for various purposes, such as display, generation or manipulation.